# Sorting lists as a functions in (Python code)

Tags: python, list, sorting, recursion, scripting

I want to code some functions but I am having some difficulties.

The first function is "func", which basically is like 'partition'. This function takes a list and two integers (num1 and num2). The function "looks" at the sub list starting index of the first number (num1) and ending (not exclusive) the index of the last number (num2).

A new variable - "here", will be the last element in the sub list.
This function ("func") replaces the order of organs so that each sub list what organs are too small to be left to "here", and all the other organs will be in his right. The function returns the index of the new location of "here".

I have defined the variable "position", the index of the location that the left limbs smaller than "here". At the beginning of the run "position" will be equal to num1.
The function "func" switches on the indexes of all the organs of the sub list, not including the last element. If the arm is less than the current index here we replace it from the organ instead of the here and promote the here in one.

Finally, replace "here" ( the organ in last place in the sub list ) and the organ instead of the "position".
The function "func" returns the position.

Here is an example code which I have created ( welcome to tell me what you think about it ):

```
def func(lst, num1, num2):
    position = num1
    here = lst[num2 - 1]
    for i in range (len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] < here:
            lst[position], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[position]
            position = position +1
    lst[position], lst[len(lst) - 1] = here, lst[position]
    return position
```

This code is good, at least it works.
If you press F5 and write in the shell:

```
>>> lst = [41, 7, 17, 3, 24, 16]
>>> func(lst, 0, len(lst))
    2
```

Now, I want to implement another function, "a_func2". This function takes a list and two numbers ( num1 and num2 ). This function sorts only the sub list begins with num1 and ends with (not included) num2, same way like I wrote before, in the beginning of the question.
The difference is that this time I want to use the function "func" I've coded in order to sort the organs on the left and right of "here". In other words, it's kinda like recursive function, right?

```
 def a_func2(lst, num1, num2):
 ##HAVE NO IDEA
```

Or in other words, the sort in the first time is not enough. "func" order the list only one time. I want the second function, "a_func2" to sort the list untill the list will be in a perfect order. Something like that.

I got stuck on this part, and I do not exactly know what to do. Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide an example? The problem explanation is quite long and an example would make the things clearer.

Comment: I've wrote a code as the example. What will happen if you paste my code, run it, write in the shell the lst and call "func". Can you think about another example?
Thanks!

Comment: I mean the example of correct behavior of your a_func2.

Comment: Take a look at [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), which seems to be what you're trying to implement. Your `func` performs the "choose a pivot" and "partition" operations, and now you're trying to do the step "recursively apply the above steps to the sub-lists".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to implement [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). You already have the "partitioning" part of the algorithm done, and you want to implement the recursive part. It's pretty simple: partition the list, and then quicksort the left and right halves.

```
def func(lst, num1, num2):
    position = num1
    here = lst[num2 - 1]
    for i in range (num1, num2):
        if lst[i] < here:
            lst[position], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[position]
            position = position +1
    lst[position], lst[num2-1] = here, lst[position]
    return position

def quicksort(lst, num1, num2):
    if num2 - num1 <= 1:
        #this portion of lst is only zero or one elements long. Don't need to do anything.
        return
    partition = func(lst, num1, num2)
    #sort left half of lst
    quicksort(lst, num1, partition)
    #sort right half
    quicksort(lst, partition+1, num2)

x = [16,23,15,8,42,4]
quicksort(x, 0, len(x))
print x
```

Result:

```
[4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
```

Note that I had to modify `func` a little bit. Mostly, replacing all instances of `len(lst)-1` with `num2-1`. This is because the former gets the index of the last element of the list, and the latter gets the index of the last element of the *sublist*, which is what you want.